Docker glob (conditional) COPY of `node_module[s]` failing
In my docker file I have
# [s] in brackets to allow for the folder to not exist
# This is /not/ best practice, but this lets us reuse packages already downloaded
# And we care more about saving bandwith
COPY package.json node_module[s]/ ./

inspired by Conditional COPY/ADD in Dockerfile? . When I run
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build

everything works fine with or without node_modules existing.
When I run
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker compose build

if node_modules does not exist, things work just fine. But if it does exist, then I get this complete nonsense error:

failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref cf300a02-19ca-4a07-951f-080a0c0ef0b0::x8jv3lm9rqctbwfjb6qsha2kk: "/usr/bin/python3": not found

/usr/bin/python3 is not at all what I'm trying to copy.
$ docker -v
Docker version 24.0.7, build 24.0.7-0ubuntu2~22.04.1

How can I get things to work?

You usually want to include node_modules in a .dockerignore file, so that it is never copied into the image.  RUN npm ci will install the packages from your package.json/package-lock.json files.  This avoids problems if the host OS or system library stack doesn't match what's in the container.  Make sure to not overwrite the image directory with a volume mount!

@DavidMaze I was unaware of "clean install"; thanks for the tip. But my team is often traveling and working off of mobile hotspot with spotty reception, so using downloads already on the disk is a trade off we're generally willing to make. The goal here is to make docker build work even if a dev has not installed things locally. (Using fewer, smaller packages being ideal, but a separate conversation)

While writing up this question, I discovered that ""/usr/bin/python3": not found" is actually the problem. I happen to have symlinks in my node_modules
$ find ./node_modules/ -type l -ls | grep python
 53108278      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     user           16 Sep 10  2023 ./node_modules/cpu-features/build/node_gyp_bins/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
 53108265      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 user     user           16 Sep 10  2023 ./node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto/build/node_gyp_bins/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3

I guess buildkit changed how symlinks are handled, but fails to provide adiquate error messages. (I still normally use DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 because the output is more useful).
But then WHY does COPY package.json node_modules/ ./ work???
